# PostgreSQL "?" argument placeholder does not work for "WITH"

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am trying to use `?` in the following way (I use it in Golang to generate query, but it seems like it is not Go dependent):

```
WITH Tmp(name, enabled) AS (
    VALUES(?, ?),(?, ?)
) 
UPDATE table_groups 
    SET enabled = (SELECT enabled 
                   FROM Tmp 
                   WHERE table_groups.name=Tmp.name) 
WHERE table_groups.name IN (SELECT name FROM Tmp)
```

getting:

```
syntax error at or near ","
```

If I substitute `?` in the above statement by concrete values, everything works fine. Is there a problem using `?` with `WITH` and how would I get around it? Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated: you do not need the scalar subquery.

Comment: I thought Postgres only works with numbered placeholders, i.e. `$1`.

Comment: What driver package are you using to work with pgsql? You know, Go does not include drivers for any RDBMS in its standard library, so it's essential to tell us what you're doing. If you're using `github.com/lib/pq`, [the docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq) mention only `$n`-style parameters, as @Ainar-G suggested. IOW, formats of query placeholders are driver-specific, not something universal.

Comment: @kostix: thanks, I am, indeed, using pq

Answer (score 1):

Go doesn't support this at of the box.

You can use [jmoiron/sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) if you want this functional

example using sqlx (from [docs](https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/)):

```
var levels = []int{4, 6, 7}
query, args, err := sqlx.In("SELECT * FROM users WHERE level IN (?);", levels)

// sqlx.In returns queries with the `?` bindvar, we can rebind it for our backend
query = db.Rebind(query)
rows, err := db.Query(query, args...)
```